# PHP Website browser console Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am facing issue Js Uncaught SyntaxError PHP Website

Details of query :

URL is http://www.matoshreenisarg.com/about-us/dg
This URL should be redirected to 404 but this is not redirecting appearing inspect  console error

```
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
bootstrap.min.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.min.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.fancybox.pack.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
isotope.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
owl.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.gmap.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.easing.min.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
masterslider.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wow.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
script.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*
```

Comment: Use another browser? Firefox clearly tells me what is wrong. But even with something like Chrome, you can work it out.

Comment: your files are messy. `<!DOCTYPE html>` in `js files`. Don't abuse it man

Answer (score 1):

use

> /

in every external script/css call

For Example

> src="/js/jquery.js" instead of src="js/jquery.js"
>
> href="/css/style.css" instead of href="css/style.css"

Comment: yes, I don't think, there are any doctype tag in js file. Please cross check for the same.